# Quotation marks appear with some strings and not others. How can I make all strings the same?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, quotation-marks

I am reading in a csv file to a dictionary, transforming the data as needed, and writing it to a new csv file.

The original csv file has a column where some strings (words) are in double quotation marks while other strings are not in quotation marks.

Like this:

```
FOODS;CALS
"PIZZA";600
"PIZZA";600
"BURGERS";500
"PIZZA";600
PASTA;400
"PIZZA";600
SALAD;100
CHICKEN WINGS;300
"PIZZA";600
"PIZZA";600
```

After I write this column to my output file, it looks like the array below, where the words from the original CSV that were in quotation marks now have three quotations around them and others have none:

```
FAVORITE_FOOD;VOTES
"""PIZZA""";6
"""BURGERS""";1
PASTA;1
SALAD;1
CHICKEN WINGS;1
```

I need to remove the quotation marks so my final csv looks like this:

```
FAVORITE_FOOD;VOTES
PIZZA;6
BURGERS;1
PASTA;1
SALAD;1
CHICKEN WINGS;1
```

Here is how I'm reading in the file:

```
with open(input_data_txt, "r") as file:
    # This enables skipping the header line.
    skipped = islice(file, 1, None)
    for i, line in enumerate(skipped, 2):

        try:
            food, cals = line.split(';')
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

And here is how I'm writing it:

```
with open(food_txt, 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=';')
    for i in final_array:
        wr.writerow(i)
```

Comment: Can you show how you're reading the input and writing the output? Are you using the `csv` module for instance in one case but not the other?

Comment: @JonClements Added to my answer how I'm reading and writing the file.

Comment: Is there any reason to remove the quotation marks... any sensible system that can import semi-colon delimited files won't mind those at all and will recognise the `"`s as delimiters so can remove those as well...

Comment: Is that last `"PIZZA"600` actually what you have - eg: it's a malformed row... am I correct in assuming that what you're doing is counting the occurrences of each value in the "FAVORITE_FOOD" column - as that's what your output appears to be but you don't have any code in your post that shows you trying to do that?

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. Please don't add "SOLVED" or similar; an accepted answer directly anl unambiguously marks your question as resolved. If you want to add an answer of your own, you are of course welcome to it. (The edit history contains all previous versions of the question's text if you want to repurpose it.)

Comment: @tripleee OK, thanks for the knowledge. In this case, I accepted an answer that helped me solve my problem. But because that solution wasn't exactly the solution I used, I figured it merited adding my solution. Perhaps I could have put my solution in a response to the accepted answer, unless that is also ill-advised?

Comment: You can leave a comment on the accepted answer, of course, but if it's worth mentioning at all, probably posting an answer of your own is warranted. However, I'm not convinced it's useful here (though I vaguely wonder why you included slash in your variant; was it just a typo?)

Comment: I had previously learned that I needed the slash in this situation so I did it without even thinking about it. Now I look back at the accepted answer and see that he didn't use the slash. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Your sample data doesn't contain any slashes so probably not in scope for this question anyway,

Comment: OK. Well, it works both ways -- with the slash or not -- so I don't see the problem.

Comment: Probably the tool which writes the triple quotation marks in the first place is the one which should be fixed, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triple quotes are likely added by the `csv` module to escape the existing quotes.

So instead of something like:

```
csvwriter.writeline(food, vote)
```

Try something like:

```
csvwriter.writeline(food.strip('"'), vote)
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me solve the problem. After reading in the file, I just created a line like this: food = food.strip('"') and this effectively removed the unnecessary quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace`:

```
file = open(r"PY.csv")
text = file.read()
text = text.split()
for i in range(len(text)):
    text[i] = text[i].replace('"',"")
```

Than you will have a list like this:

```
PIZZA
PIZZA
BURGERS
PIZZA
PASTA
PIZZA
SALAD
CHICKEN WINGS
PIZZA
PIZZA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv.DictReader` so you can address columns by name, a `collections.Counter` to *count* the number of each occurrence of a food, and then use `csv.writer` to output them accordingly, eg:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('input_file') as fin, open('output_file', 'wb') as fout:
    # Count occurrences of each FOODS type
    votes = Counter(row['FOODS'] for row in csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter=';'))
    # Create a csv.writer around the output file and write the header columns
    csvout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=';')
    csvout.writerow(['FAVORITE_FOOD', 'VOTES'])
    # Write the name and vote counts to the file
    csvout.writerows(votes.items())
```